# Why bytes in c# are named byte and sbyte unlike other integral types?

Tags: c#

I was just flipping through the specification and found that byte is odd. Others are short, ushort, int, uint, long, and ulong. Why this naming of sbyte and byte instead of byte and ubyte?

Comment: There was quite the debate on the CLR design team over this question back when the type system was being designed. As you can see, the "bytes are by definition unsigned" contingent won the argument.

Comment: @Eric: Thank goodness for that. I suspect that those who were arguing for signed bytes had never experienced the pain of using them in Java ;)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

It's a matter of semantics.  When you think of a byte you usually (at least I do) think of an 8-bit value from 0-255.  So that's what `byte` is.  The less common interpretation of the binary data is a signed value (`sbyte`) of -128 to 127.

With integers, it's more intuitive to think in terms of signed values, so that's what the basic name style represents.  The `u` prefix then allows access to the less common unsigned semantics.

Comment: +1. Note that in Java, a `byte` ranges from -128 to 127, though (and there are no unsigned types at all, unless you count `char`).

Comment: I know a few things about Java, and I still think of a byte as 0-255 (or rather 00 to FF, I hardly ever treat them as numbers).

Answer (score 12):

The reason a type "byte", without any other adjective, is often unsigned while a type "int", without any other adjective, is often signed, is that unsigned 8-bit values are often more practical (and thus widely used) than signed bytes, but signed integers of larger types are often more practical (and thus widely used) than unsigned integers of such types.

There is a common linguistic principle that, if a "thing" comes in two types, "usual" and "unusual", the term "thing" without an adjective means a "usual thing"; the term "unusual thing" is used to refer to the unusual type.  Following that principle, since unsigned 8-bit quantities are more widely used than signed ones, the term "byte" without modifiers refers to the unsigned flavor.  Conversely, since signed integers of larger sizes are more widely used than their unsigned equivalents, terms like "int" and "long" refer to the signed flavors.

As for the reason behind such usage patterns, if one is performing maths on numbers of a certain size, it generally won't matter--outside of comparisons--whether the numbers are signed or unsigned.  There are times when it's convenient to regard them as signed (it's more natural, for example, to say think in terms of adding -1 to a number than adding 65535) but for the most part, declaring numbers to be signed doesn't require any extra work for the compiler except when one is either performing comparisons or extending the numbers to a larger size.  Indeed, if anything, signed integer math may be faster than unsigned integer math (since unsigned integer math is required to behave predictably in case of overflow, whereas unsigned math isn't).

By contrast, since 8-bit operands must be extended to type 'int' before performing any math upon them, the compiler must generate different code to handle signed and unsigned operands; in most cases, the signed operands will require more code than unsigned ones.  Thus, in cases where it wouldn't matter whether an 8-bit value was signed or unsigned, it often makes more sense to use unsigned values.  Further, numbers of larger types are often decomposed into a sequence of 8-bit values or reconstituted from such a sequence.  Such operations are easier with 8-bit unsigned types than with 8-bit signed types.  For these reasons, among others, unsigned 8-bit values are used much more commonly than signed 8-bit values.

Note that in the C language, "char" is an odd case, since all characters within the C character set are required to translate as non-negative values (so machines which use an 8-bit char type with an EBCDIC character set are required to have "char" be unsigned), but an "int" is required to hold all values that a "char" can hold (so machines where both "char" and "int" are 16 bits are required to have "char" be signed).

Comment: @siride: And what is the heritage of C#?  To the extent that it also folds in non-C languages, the same principle actually applies even more strongly with those.  The original Apple BASIC, for example, had unsigned 8-bit and signed 16-bit as the two available math types.

Comment: The relevance is minimal since C# has its own rules and its own runtime system, where, e.g., overflow is checked (not possible in C without assembly hacks or non-standard compiler extensions).  In any case, it's not relevant to the question because your explanation of why bytes are unsigned is only relevant to C, not C# (in which case, it'd be just as true for shorts as it would for bytes, but shorts follow the normal patter of short/ushort).

Comment: @siride: Perhaps my answer as written seemed overly C-centric, but that wasn't my intention.  Many languages over the years have had similar semantics, though I'm not sure which ones came first (e.g. was Pascal invented before or after the original Apple "Integer" BASIC?  I think the reason for the behavior is as I said: bytes are more often used as constituents of a larger type.  Note also that if a language doesn't check for overflow, one can convert a pair of bytes to a signed or unsigned int by using lsb+256*msb.  If bytes were signed, that wouldn't work.

Comment: @siride: Why does nobody like my answer, which provides more historical background than the accepted one?  The fact that in C# bytes are "by default" unsigned and other types are signed is largely a result of historical convention.

Comment: -1 The question is not about "when is it more convenient/efficient to use signed vs. unsigned?", the question was about the naming convention. Your answer doesn't even talk about why the naming is different.

Comment: @JesseWebb: I stated historic reasons why, in cases where it didn't matter whether something was signed or unsigned, it was much better to use unsigned values for 8-bit types, but for larger types it didn't matter.  Consequently, unsigned 8-bit values are used a lot more than signed ones.  A linguistic principle I would have thought was self-explanatory dictates that if there are two types of "thing", "usual" and "unusual", it makes more sense to have the term "thing" by itself refer to the former, and use the term "unusual thing" to refer to the latter.  How does that not answer the question?

Comment: Maybe re-read your answer, I don't think it says what you think it does. The main point of the 1st section seems to be "declaring numbers to be signed doesn't require any extra work for the compiler". This does not address the naming convention OR the historical 'common' usage of either signed/unsigned types. The 2nd section goes *even* deeper into the compiler efficiency, without address the naming/commonality once again. And the 3rd part is just a comment about the C language, again unrelated to the question. It's a good answer with helpful historical info, just posted on the wrong question.

Comment: @JesseWebb: How do you like it now?

Comment: @JesseWebb: Glad you like it.  Thanks for your comments.  BTW, it's funny that when I wrote the original answer I hadn't learned nor figured out why `char` was sometimes signed and sometimes unsigned, even though I had in fact worked on a machine with 16-bit `char` where it *had* to be signed, and I've worked on machines (though not programmed them in C) which used EBCDIC as the character set (an 8-bit character set which maps the digits 0-9 to codes 0xF0-0xF9).

Comment: I liked your answer as well.   +1 from me.